# Django: Make a single DB call instead of iterating QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following code that iterates the `tags` queryset, and for each item, creates a `Department` object and adds it to the `departments` list:

```
departments: List[Department] = []

tags = Tag.objects.filter(type="department")

for tag in tags:
    dept_id = tag.reference_id
    dept_name = tag.name

    parent_tag = Tag.objects.get(type="department", reference_id=tag.parent_reference_id)
    dept_parent_id = parent_tag.reference_id

    departments.append(Department(dept_id, dept_name, dept_parent_id))
```

However, as you can see, it is making multiple DB calls via `Tag.objects.get()`, which seems highly inefficient. Is there an efficient way to populate that `departments` list without making so many DB calls?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is "in" in your query.

check [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/)

```
Entry.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 4])
Entry.objects.filter(headline__in='abc')
```

so in your case you can use the the following example :

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(id=some_id, type="department").values('id')
tags_list = [tag['id'] for tag in tags]
parent_tag = Tag.objects.get(id__in=tags_list, type="department")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used parts of the answer from @Vanda to write the following solution, and this solves my problem.

```
departments: List[Department] = []

tags = Tag.objects.filter(type="department")
parents_set = {tag.parent_reference_id for tag in tags}

for tag in tags:
    dept_id = tag.reference_id
    dept_name = tag.name

    dept_parent_id = tag.parent_reference_id
    if(dept_parent_id not in parents_set):
        dept_parent_id = None

    departments.append(Department(dept_id, dept_name, dept_parent_id))
```